# getExternalFilesDirs does not return the SD card, only internal/built-in storage

Tags: android, storage

[getExternalFilesDirs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)) is supposed to return my app's private data folder both on internal storage and external storage. On all my phones this works properly (various LG, Samsung, and Moto phones, spanning releases 4.4 to 11), but on many of my customer's phones it doesn't, with only the internal storage folder being returned(/storage/emulated/0...); their SD card is missing (/storage/abc-123/...). I'd put it down to the huge variety of phone manufactures but in one case a customer's Samsung S10 doesn't see the SD card, whereas my S10e does (both running android 10). Unfortunately these are play store customers so I can't physically debug these issues.

So what's going on here? Why does this method fail to include the SD card on some phones and not others? I've tried calling it in a loop, and I've tried calling from both my activities' context and also application's context  { getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDirs(null) } and nothing helps, I always get the same results. I've even tried getting directory listings from /storage but that never works either, including on my phones.

I don't think it's an issue of SAF, since this is my app's data folder, which is always private to my app, and as far as I know even in android 12 you are allowed to use the Java File api to access your private data folder. But keep in mind this isn't a matter of the File API failing, the problem is getExternalFilesDirs() not returning more than one path.

And of course these same customers swear that other apps can see their external SD card. Of course those apps might be using SAF. But that still doesn't explain why getExternalFilesDirs() gives inconsistent results on virtually the same hardware (Samsung s10 vs s10e).

This has been asked in various forms in the past, but never recently, and a lot has changed since 2015, so none of the advice from back then is relevant(I have read all those posts and tried it all, of course). Also, new in my question is the specific condition of two near identical phones running what should be identical software releases, one with the  getExternalFilesDirs() result including the SD card and one not. So I think this merits a new post.

Comment: "getExternalFilesDirs is supposed to return my app's data folder both on internal storage (/data/data/<package_name>) and external storage (Android/data/<package_name>, if present)" -- it is supposed to return what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), not what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: "Unfortunately these are play store customers so I can't physically debug these issues" -- there are lots of remote logging solutions, including some (e.g., AppSpector) that let you get a live look at what you are logging (e.g., via Timber integration). Perhaps those devices *are* returning removable storage values, but there is something about the path that is tripping up your app, or something else between the `getExternalFilesDirs()` call and your use of the results that has a bug.

Comment: Terms are confusing for sure - direct from the docs:  "Returns absolute paths to application-specific directories on all shared/external storage devices where the application can place persistent files it owns. These files are internal to the application, and not typically visible to the user as media." This does include the internal (call it built-in) storage as well as external.

Comment: `getExternalFilesDirs is supposed to return my app's data folder both on internal storage (/data/data/<package_name>/files) ` No not at all. That path is returned by getFilesDir().

Comment: `and external storage (Android/data/<package_name>/files, if present). ` That is always present. But now you mention only a relative path. Why? A full path would be `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package>/files`. But that has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card.

Comment: A path in a removable micro sd card would look like storage/AB12-344C/Android/data/<package>/files and is mostly returned as second item of getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: sorry it seems adding the paths only confused things - was trying to clarify since there was the comment about external vs internal storage, etc. In any case it's not an issue of an incorrect path, but an entirely missing path, that of the SD card. Your (first) comment about getExternalFilesDirs() is wrong however - it's supposed to return two paths: the internal storage  and (if present) the external storage. Two or more, actually, since an USB OTG device can also show up there (but often doesn't).

Comment: I just noticed from the docs say of getExternalFilesDirs() that "Shared storage devices returned here are considered a stable part of the device, including physical media slots under a protective cover. The returned paths do not include transient devices, such as USB flash drives connected to handheld devices.". So maybe some android devices mark the SD slot as "non-stable"? But if so, what API can be used to get these "unstable" paths?